# Custom time struct to time_t

Tags: c, date, datetime, optimization

In my current project I have a C struct to hold a timestamp, which looks like this:

```
struct timestamp {
   uint16_t year;
   uint8_t month;
   uint8_t day;
   uint8_t hour;
   uint8_t min;
   uint8_t second;
}
```

Now I want to calculate the difference between two of these timestamps in seconds. For now I'm converting my timestamp struct to the C standard struct `struct tm` (defined in `<time.h>`). Then I convert the struct to `time_t` with `mtkime()`, which takes a pointer to a `struct tm` and returns a `time_t`. And `difftime()` to calculate the difference between two `time_t`'s in seconds.

I don't want to write my own `difftime()`, since I do not want to deal with leapyears or even worse leap seconds by myself, and I don't use the `struct tm` in my code because it holds a lot of values I don't frequently need (like week-day or year-day).

Here is an example, what I do at the moment:

```
void customTimestampToStructTM(struct customTimestamp *in, struct tm *out) {
  out->tm_year = in->year;
  out->tm_mon  = in->mon;
  out->tm_mday = in->day;
  out->tm_hour = in->hour;
  out->tm_min  = in->min;
  out->tm_sec  = in->sec;
}

void someFunction() {
   struct customTimestamp c1;
   struct customTimestamp c2;
   // Fill c1 and c2 with data here.

   struct tm tmpC1;
   struct tm tmpC2;

   customTimestampToStructTM(&c1, &tmpC1);
   customTimestampToStructTM(&c2, &tmpC2);

   double diffInSeconds = difftime(mktime(tmpC1), mktime(tmpC2));
   // Use diffInSeconds
}
```

This works, but seem incredibly inefficient. How can I speed this up? I read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/) that `mktime` doesn't use the other fields in the `struct tm` - except for `isdst`. Is there a convenient way to convert *my* struct to `time_t`, without using `struct tm` as a bridge and without the need to deal with leapyears/seconds?

**To clarify:** `time_t` holds dates in amount of milliseconds passed since a specific date (1 Jan 1970).

Comment: How did you determine it is inefficient?

Comment: `static void customTimestampToStructTM(...) ` will allow the compiler to inline the whole bunch of assignments. Look at the the assembler output: the whole assignment will probable have vanished completely.

Comment: @2501 I did saved the date once in `struct tm` and once in my format. I need to keep *a lot* of these dates in memory (around 20 million) and iterate over them quite frequently (and need the difference). The difference was pretty small (around 100ms) for one iteration, but I was just wondering if there is another way, since I'll do thousands of these iterations and don't want to fill my memory with not needed extra information.

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive Why don't you only keep time_t? Getting the diff is cheaper and time_t takes less memory.

Comment: for gcc it is `gcc -S -other-flags mysource.c`

Comment: C11 says: "tm_wday and tm_yday are ignored" on call to mktime

Comment: tm_isdst should be -1. See: [libc docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Broken_002ddown-Time.html)

Comment: `customTimestampToStructTM()` is a problem as 1) it does not set `tm_isdst`, 2) other required fields, 3) may not use the same year & month offset.   Suggest start with `memset(out, 0, sizeof *out)` and set `tm_isdst=-1`.

Comment: 1) Is `timestamp` use to represent _local_ time or universal time?  2) If local, what time zone should be used - the current one only?  3) If local, how do you want to handle DST?  4) It seems the concern about efficiency is overlooking correct functionality.

Comment: @chux The time is saved as local EST without DST adjustments. I had the dst in the back of my head, but wasn't thinking about it right now.

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive: Don't do that. Always keep your timestamps in UTC. Only convert to local time when displaying. That way you'll see sane timewise-sorted lists even near the end of DST; then, users will see events in the order they occurred, even if the displayed time of the events jumps back by a hour exactly when DST ends. Every other approach leads to glitches.

Answer (score 3):

`mktime` [and `localtime`] are non-trivial for all edge cases. They're also highly optimized, so you're unlikely to do better speedwise.

So, just use them [doing the fast fill of (e.g.) `struct tm temp` you're already doing].

But, a speedup is to add `time_t tod` to your struct. Fill it from `mktime` *once* when you create your struct. This can save many repetitive/duplicate calls to `mktime`.

You can even defer the `mktime` call (i.e. only some of your structs may need it). Set `tod` to a sentinel value (e.g. -2). When you actually need to use `tod`, fill it from `mktime` if `tod` is the sentinel value

Answer (score 0):

I shall assume the timestamps always refer to UTC time, in which case Daylight Savings Time does not apply (and you'll want to specify `tm.isdst = 0`).

(I suspect that it would be optimal in this case to have the `time_t` in UTC, but the broken-down fields in local time. Below, I'll just assume that the local timezone is UTC, with no DST changes.)

Personally, I'd save both the `time_t` and the split fields, and use helper functions to set/modify the timestamps.

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct timestamp {
    time_t  packed;
    int16_t year;
    int8_t  month;
    int8_t  day;
    int8_t  hour;
    int8_t  min;
    int8_t  sec;
};

static inline int set_timestamp_time(struct timestamp *const ref, const time_t when)
{
    struct tm temp = { 0 };

    if (!gmtime_r(&when, &temp))
        return ERANGE; /* Year didn't fit. */

    ref->packed = when;
    ref->year   = temp.tm_year + 1900;
    ref->month  = temp.tm_mon  + 1;
    ref->day    = temp.tm_mday;
    ref->hour   = temp.tm_hour;
    ref->min    = temp.tm_min;
    ref->sec    = temp.tm_sec;

    return 0;
}

static inline int set_timestamp(struct timestamp *const ref,
                                const int year, const int month, const int day,
                                const int hour, const int min, const int sec)
{
    struct tm temp = { 0 };

    temp.tm_year = year - 1900;
    temp.tm_mon  = month - 1;
    temp.tm_mday = day;
    temp.tm_hour = hour;
    temp.tm_min  = min;
    temp.tm_sec  = sec;

    /* We assume timestamps are in UTC, and Daylight Savings Time does not apply. */
    temp.tm_isdst = 0;

    ref->packed = mktime(&temp);

    ref->year  = temp.tm_year + 1900;
    ref->month = temp.tm_mon + 1;
    ref->day   = temp.tm_mday;
    ref->hour  = temp.tm_hour;
    ref->min   = temp.tm_min;
    ref->sec   = temp.tm_sec;

    return 0;
}
```

`set_timestamp()` sets the timestamp based on split fields (year, month, day, hour, minute, second), whereas `set_timestamp_time()` sets it based on POSIX time. Both functions always update all timestamp fields.

This allows fast access to both the Unix time, and the split fields, but uses slightly more memory (8 bytes per timestamp, typically; 160 megabytes additional memory for 20 million records).

---

If you do not need the **exact** number of seconds between two timestamps, but only use the `time_t` to compare whether one is before or after another, then I recommend using a single `int64_t` to describe your timestamps:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

/* Timestamps can be compared as integers, like POSIX time_t's.
 * The difference between two timestamps is at least their
 * difference in seconds, but may be much larger.
 *
 * Zero is not a valid timestamp!
*/

typedef int64_t  timestamp;

#define TIMESTAMP_YEAR(t)  ((int64_t)(t) / 67108864)
#define TIMESTAMP_MONTH(t) (((uint32_t)(t) >> 22) & 15)
#define TIMESTAMP_DAY(t)   (((uint32_t)(t) >> 17) & 31)
#define TIMESTAMP_HOUR(t)  (((uint32_t)(t) >> 12) & 31)
#define TIMESTAMP_MIN(t)   (((uint32_t)(t) >>  6) & 63)
#define TIMESTAMP_SEC(t)    ((uint32_t)(t)        & 63)

static inline time_t timestamp_time(const timestamp t, struct tm *const tm_to)
{
    struct tm  temp = { 0 };
    time_t     result;
    uint32_t   u = t & 67108863U;

    temp.tm_sec  = u & 63; u >>= 6;
    temp.tm_min  = u & 63; u >>= 6;
    temp.tm_hour = u & 31; u >>= 5;
    temp.tm_mday = u & 31; u >>= 5;
    temp.tm_mon  = u - 1;
    temp.tm_year = ((int64_t)t / 67108864) - 1900;

    /* UTC time, thus Daylight Savings Time does not apply. */
    temp.tm_isdst = 0;

    result = mktime(&temp);

    if (tm_to)
        *tm_to = temp;

    return result;
}

static inline double difftimestamp(const timestamp t1, const timestamp t2)
{
    return difftime(timestamp_time(t1, NULL), timestamp_time(t2, NULL));
}

static inline timestamp set_timestamp_time(const time_t when, struct tm *const tm_to)
{
    struct tm  temp = { 0 };

    if (!gmtime_r(&when, &temp))
        return 0;

    if (tm_to)
        *tm_to = temp;

    return (int64_t)67108864 * ((int64_t)temp.tm_year + 1900)
         + (int64_t)((temp.tm_mon + 1) << 22)
         + (int64_t)(temp.tm_mday << 17)
         + (int64_t)(temp.tm_hour << 12)
         + (int64_t)(temp.tm_min << 6)
         + (int64_t)temp.tm_sec;
}

static inline timestamp set_timestamp(const int year, const int month, const int day,
                                      const int hour, const int min, const int sec,
                                      struct tm *const tm_to, time_t *const time_to)
{
    struct tm  temp = { 0 };

    temp.tm_year = year - 1900;
    temp.tm_mon  = month - 1;
    temp.tm_mday = day;

    temp.tm_hour = hour;
    temp.tm_min  = min;
    temp.tm_sec  = sec;

    temp.tm_isdst = 0; /* Since timestamps are in UTC, Daylight Savings Time does not apply. */

    if (time_to)
        *time_to = mktime(&temp);

    if (tm_to)
        *tm_to = temp;

    return (int64_t)67108864 * ((int64_t)temp.tm_year + 1900)
         + (int64_t)((temp.tm_mon + 1) << 22)
         + (int64_t)(temp.tm_mday << 17)
         + (int64_t)(temp.tm_hour << 12)
         + (int64_t)(temp.tm_min << 6)
         + (int64_t)temp.tm_sec;
}
```

The idea here is that you can compare two `timestamp`s trivially; `a < b` if and only if timestamp `a` is before `b`; `a == b` if and only if the timestamps refer to the same second, and `a > b` if and only if `a` is after `b`. At the same time, the accessor macros `TIMESTAMP_YEAR(a)`, `TIMESTAMP_MONTH(a)`, `TIMESTAMP_DAY(a)`, `TIMESTAMP_HOUR(a)`, `TIMESTAMP_MIN(a)`, and `TIMESTAMP_SEC(a)` allow very fast access to the individual date and time components. (On typical Intel/AMD 64-bit hardware, it may be even faster than accessing byte-sized fields.)

The `difftimestamp()` function yields the exact number of seconds between two timestamps, but it is quite slow. (As I mentioned, this approach is best only if you don't need this, or only need it rarely.)

`timestamp_time()` converts a timestamp to a `time_t`, optionally saving the `struct tm` fields to a specified pointer (if not `NULL`).

`set_timestamp_time()` returns a timestamp based on a `time_t`. If the year does not fit in an int, it will return 0 (which is NOT a valid timestamp). If the second parameter is not `NULL`, the corresponding `struct tm` is stored there.

`set_timestamp()` returns a timestamp based on year, month, day, hour, minute, and second. If they refer to an impossible date or time, they are corrected (by `mktime()`). If the seventh parameter is not NULL, the resulting `struct tm` is stored there. If the eighth parameter is not NULL, then the resulting `time_t` is stored there.